# WCF/REST return group associated with tags, fix datacontracts & datamembers

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

So im stuck on a few things in each part below, they are pretty trivial to most of you on stack so just wondering if I can get help with three issues I have in the below code segments the issues I have are:

My Operation contract looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "")]
    List<Tag> GetTagCollection();
    #endregion
```

My datacontracts look like this:

```
[DataContract(Name="Student")]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember(Name = "StudentID")]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My service work looks like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
public class RawDataService : IReceiveData
{

    public List<Group> GetGroupsCollection(string TagName)
    {
        List<Group> groups = (from g in _program.Groups // _program does not exist notsure what goes here
                              where
                                  (from t in g.Tags where t.Name == TagName select t).Count() > 0
                              select g).ToList();
        return groups;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Because `GetGroupsCollection` expects a `TagName` parameter, you'll want to include that in your uri template:

```
/whatever/{TagName}
```

in order for it to be passed to the method when invoked by WCF REST. [Uri Template (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx)

2.Your contracts look ok, but you don't need names when the name is the same as the class/member name.  .Net will figure this out for you.  But it doesn't hurt...

3.Your service has to be pulling data from somewhere, right?  For now, you could simply new up a collection of Groups to use for testing and return that.  Database connections, ORM, etc. are probably beyond the scope of this question.

This should generate enough to play with:

```
var tempGroups = new[]{
    new Group { 
        Name = "Hello", 
        Tags = new[] { 
            new Tag { Name = "Tag1"}, 
            new Tag { Name =  "Tag2"}
        }
    },
   new Group { 
        Name = "World", 
        Tags = new[] { 
            new Tag { Name = "Tag1"}, 
            new Tag { Name = "Tag2"}
            new Tag { Name = "Tag3"}
        }
    }
};
```

Just replace `_program.Groups` with `tempGroups`.

Comment: inside the `GetGroupsCollection` method before your Linq query.

Comment: if I try that new is underlined saying you cant convert type [] array to list?

Comment: then import System.Linq and do tempGroups.ToList()